# Pacman Maze Creation using Factory Method Design Pattern

Tags: java, factory-pattern, maze, pacman

I am currently in the middle of a project where I am creating a framework for a Pacman game using several Design Patterns. I'm looking to use the Factory Method. The idea is that the framework will support mazes but will not know what mazes will be deployed at runtime.

I understand how to use the Factory Method, it's more the content for the maze creation that I'm drawing a blank on. As in what methods or variables I should be including or storing in the MazeFactory and the abstract Maze class. I'm not looking for any coding help per se just the information that maybe the classes should be providing for the above spec.

Apologies if this question is against the nature of the forum or has been repeated in some way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you refering to the Static Factory Method pattern?

Comment: No, it's the Factory Method as defined by GoF for instantiating instances.

Comment: picking a pattern before working out the logic is putting the cart before the horse.  work out what you need to do then apply patterns to solve the problem as needed

Comment: This link is great for the algorithm http://www.contralogic.com/2d-pac-man-style-maze-generation/